# How do I add another condition to this while loop? (PHP)

Tags: php, while-loop

The below code cycles through an array of posts and displays a listing that is assigned to each post. I'd like to limit the number of posts that is being cycled though to 15. In this case, I believe $count is the number of posts that have been cycled though. How do I add a condition to end the while if $count > 15.

Both $count and $real_count have been initialized at 0 previously.

```
<div class="carousel owl-carousel vertical-carousel clearfix" data-autoheight="<?php echo $autoheight; ?>" data-pagination="false" data-items="<?php echo esc_attr( $items ); ?>" data-autoplay="<?php echo esc_attr( $autoplay ); ?>">
            
                <?php while ( $the_essence_query->have_posts() ) : $the_essence_query->the_post(); $count++; $real_count++; ?>

                    <?php include( locate_template( 'template-parts/listing/blog-post-s3.php' ) ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div><!-- .vertical-carousel -->
```

Comment: To combine conditional expressions, use the logical operators `&&` for AND, use `||` for OR. This is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: use a `for` loop for purposes like that: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php